# Сумма n + k + ..., где каждое след. слагаемое — разность по модулю двух предыдущих

Tags: python, python-3.x

Полная формулировка задачи:

Для заданных n и k (n > k) вычислите сумму: n + k + |n - k| + ... , где каждое следующее слагаемое является разностью по модулю двух предыдущих. Вычисление прекратить, как только значение последнего слагаемого достигнет единицы. Если единица не будет достигнута до 100-го слагаемого, отобразить сумму первых 100 слагаемых.

Пример: n = 13, k = 8. Сумма = 13 + 8 + 5 + 3 + 2 + 1 = 32.

n = 8, k = 4. Единица в слагаемом не достигнута. Сумма = 272.

Были изучены только ввод-вывод, основные арифметические операции и условные операторы на элементарном уровне. Задачу требуется решить с помощью **цикла**, но сколько я не читал об этом в интернете, не могу вообще понять логики, по которой нужно строить решение.

"Код", который пытался. Первая часть (до "///") работает (нетрудно догадаться, почему). Я не понимаю, как вычислить сумму только первых 100 слагаемых и как формулировать условие, что "если до 100-го члена слагаемое != 1". По идее, сумма остаётся прежней, просто нужно взять ограниченное число слагаемых. Формулы суммы членов прогрессии использовать нельзя.

```
n = int(input('Введите натур. число: '))
k = int(input('Введите натур. число: '))

s = n + k

while abs(n - k) > 1:
    n = abs(n - k)
    k = abs(k - n)
    s += n + k
print('Сумма = ', s)

///

s100 = n + k

if abs(n - k) != 1 in range (100):
    n = abs(n - k)
    k = abs(k - n)
    s100 += n + k in range (100)
    print('Сумма первых 100 слагаемых: ', s100)
```

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: Спасибо за замечание, исправил.

Comment: Я может что-то не понимаю в задании, но это возрастающая последовательность, что должно быть равно 1?

Comment: Задание отредактировано.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Нужно добавит счетчик слагаемых в цикл.
n = int(input('Введите натур. число: '))
k = int(input('Введите натур. число: '))

s = n + k
counter = 2
while abs(n - k) != 1 and counter != 100:
    n = abs(n - k)
    k = abs(k - n)
    s += n + k
    counter += 2
print('Сумма = ', s)
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот так можно:

```
n = int(input('Enter the n: '))
k = int(input('Enter the k: '))

result = n + k
while (n != 1) and (k != 1):
    n = abs(n-k)
    k = abs(k-n)
    result += n + k
print(result)
```

**Внимание**. При некоторых входных данных программа уйдет в бесконечный цикл:

1. `n = 6`, `k = 2`
   `6 + 2 + 4 + 2 + 4 + •••`
2. `n=8`, `k=4`
   `8 + 4 + 4 + 0 + 4 + 4 + 0 + •••`
3. И их еще много

**UPD**:

```
n = int(input('Enter the n: '))
k = int(input('Enter the k: '))

addend_count = 2
result = n + k
while (n != 1) and (k != 1) and (addend_count < 100):
    n = abs(n-k)
    k = abs(k-n)
    result += n + k
    addend_count += 2
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы программа не уходила в бесконечный цикл я добавил условие:

```
n = int(input('Enter the n: '))
k = int(input('Enter the k: '))
count = 2

result = n + k
while (n != 1) and (k != 1) and (n > k):
    if (count > 100): break
    n = abs(n-k)
    k = abs(k-n)
    result += n + k
print(result)
```

Думаю, так будет правильнее.